# Can't import vlc module into Python, "not a valid Win32 application" error

Tags: python, vlc, libvlc

I am trying to use the VLC module for a python script. I have run `pip install python-vlc`

```
C:\Users\Me>pip install python-vlc
Requirement already satisfied: python-vlc in c:\python34\lib\site-packages
```

When I run 'import vlc' I get this error:

```
Python 3.4.4rc1 (v3.4.4rc1:04f3f725896c, Dec  6 2015, 17:06:10) [MSC v.1600 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import vlc
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Python34\lib\vlc.py", line 181, in <module>
    dll, plugin_path  = find_lib()
  File "C:\Python34\lib\vlc.py", line 159, in find_lib
    dll = ctypes.CDLL(p)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\ctypes\__init__.py", line 351, in __init__
    self._handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode)
OSError: [WinError 193] %1 is not a valid Win32 application
>>>
```

I have been trying to figure this out for the last couple hours, and am stumped. After searching through SO and Google for a while, I *believe* it has something to do with setting a PATH variable? But, I could be waaay off. Maybe I installed this wrong, or something, I don't know...

Comment: Did you compile VLC from source?

Comment: From github? no...

Comment: just uninstalled, and ran 

`pip install git+https://git.videolan.org/git/vlc/bindings/python.git`

Comment: You're running 64-bit Python, and `find_lib()` may have found a 32-bit VLC DLL.

Comment: Still got the same error when trying to import vlc

Comment: @eryksun hmmm, any way I could go about checking that?

Comment: Call `find_lib` and print the DLL path that it returns. Check to see if you can load the DLL via `ctypes.CDLL` in 32-bit Python.

Comment: Ran it in 32-bit, that worked, thank you @eryksun!

Comment: @eryksun I have a similar problem but I am using 64bit Conda environment. I wonder if you can help me with this. My question is here:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48086279/vlc-and-python-architecture-comatibility-issue

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Uninstall your vlc
2. Search 'libvlc.dll' on your local disk, and delete them all.
3. Install vlc(x64) again, and note that don't install it under 'program files',
4. Then it will work.